# POST method for Valence API

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am facing an issue in creating a new user through valence api.

```
var request = new RestRequest(string.Format("/d2l/api/lp/{0}/users", LP_VERSION));
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(user);
authenticator.Authenticate(client, request);
var response = client.Execute<UserData>(request);
```

So I create a `POST` request and pass object as JSon . But in Response, `userData` is not been retrieved and the `StatusCode` is coming as `Not Found`.

My question is : Why am I getting a 'Not found' status when I try to create a new user?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [API route to create a user](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#post--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-users-) has a trailing slash: `POST /d2l/api/lp/(version)/users/`. In general, the Valence Learning Framework API uses a trailing slash to call out a resource that's a collection of items, and in general to create a new single entity, you do a `POST` to the collection that aggregates those entities.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with the same solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reply. Fortunately, I figured it out. The answer is that you should not pass a Serialized Json block to the request body. The code "request.AddBody(user) should be only just a "User" object class. Thanks anyway.